# how to remove space in html table

Tags: html, css

I have requirement to distributing rows equally in table.

We assume there are 19 records in database. So we have to arrange data in following maner

```
ASC1          ASC8             ASC14
ASC2          ASC9             ASC15
ASC3          ASC10            ASC16
ASC4          ASC11            ASC17
ASC5          ASC12            ASC18
ASC6          ASC13            ASC19
ASC7
```

user will select in how many columns he want to display data. Assume he select as columns to display so output should be first column : 7 rows , second column : 6 rows and Third column: 6 rows. So basically its dynamic display.

I have completed all Logic but somehow i am getting Space in second and Third row. Here is my html output

```html
<table style='width:480px' border='1'>
  <tr>
    <td style='width:160px'>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td>ASC1</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td>ASC2</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td>ASC3</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td>ASC4</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td>ASC5</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td>ASC6</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td>ASC7</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
    </td>
    <td style='width:160px'>
      <table>
       <tr>
         <td>ASC8</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td>ASC9</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td>ASC10</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td>ASC11</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td>ASC12</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td>ASC13</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
    </td>
    <td style='width:160px'>
      <table>
       <tr>
         <td>ASC14</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td>ASC15</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td>ASC16</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td>ASC17</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td>ASC</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td>ASC</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Text ASC8 and ASC14 should align text ASC1. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a vertical align and set it to `top`:

```
table td, table td * {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

See it live:

```html
<style>
table td, table td * {
vertical-align: top;
}
</style>
<table style='width:480px' border='1'>
  <tr>
    <td style='width:160px'>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td>ASC1</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td>ASC2</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td>ASC3</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td>ASC4</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td>ASC5</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td>ASC6</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td>ASC7</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
    </td>
    <td style='width:160px'>
      <table>
       <tr>
         <td>ASC8</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td>ASC9</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td>ASC10</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td>ASC11</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td>ASC12</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td>ASC13</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
    </td>
    <td style='width:160px'>
      <table>
       <tr>
         <td>ASC14</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td>ASC15</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td>ASC16</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td>ASC17</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td>ASC</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td>ASC</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: but why we need to add it?

Comment: @Happy because otherwise the block "floats" and aligns to the center vertically.